# Python: Getting an undefine variable error when trying to call a function?

Tags: python, undefined

I'm still pretty new to Python, but it seems I've run into a problem. I get an undefined error when trying to call another function that defines that variable.

```
def unpackCon():
    unpackConfirm = input("Unpack contents?[Y/N] ")

def unpackConScript():
    if unpackConfirm == "y":
        print ("Unpack confirmed.")
    elif unpackConfirm == "n":
        print ("Unpack unconfirmed.")
    else:
        print ("Value %s is not valid.") % (unpackConfirm)
        unpackCon()

unpackCon()
unpackConScript()
```

Knowing Python, it's probably got something to do with indentation and the sorts. At first I believed it was because I called the function without defining it first, but I switched around the orders a bunch of times with no result.

Appreciate an answer!

Comment: you never defined `unpackConfirm` in the `unpackConScript()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unpackConfirm` is defined inside of `unpackCon()`, and is out of scope in the other function. You need to return the variable in order to access it.

try:

```
def unpackCon():
    unpackConfirm = input("Unpack contents?[Y/N] ").lower()
    return unpackConfirm

def unpackConScript():
    unpackConfirm = unpackCon()

    if unpackConfirm == "y":
        print ("Unpack confirmed.")
    elif unpackConfirm == "n":
        print ("Unpack unconfirmed.")
    else:
        print ("Value %s is not valid.") % (unpackConfirm)
        unpackCon()

unpackConScript()
```

Comment: How would I got about doing that? I know in some languages/cases you can label a variable as global.

Comment: I've updated my answer to help you. EDIT: I've added `.lower()` so that you can be assured you will get 'y' or 'n' and won't have to worry about capital letters

Comment: `unpackConfirm = input("Unpack contents?[Y/N] ").lower()` is better

Comment: Ah, I see now! Thanks! EDIT: And I found my own error with `print ("Value %s is not valid.") % (unpackConfirm)` and changed it to `print ("%r is not valid." % unpackConfirm)`